# Async/Await function executing twice in Discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, discord.js, aws-sdk

I've been experimenting with a Discord bot in Node.js. I came across the problem of all functions not executing linearly, but asynchronously. I managed to introduce async/await to solve this issue, but now one of my function calls executes twice and I don't know why (The command !ec2-status prints twice on a given chat even though I only call it once). The routine that reacts to a message sent is as follows:

```js
// Event: Message
client.on("messageCreate", msg => {

    // Extract metadata from message
    let msgServerID = msg.guildId;
    let msgChannelID = msg.channelId;
    let msgUserID = msg.author.id;
    let msgUsername = msg.author.username;

    // Select server and channel of current message
    let msgServer = client.guilds.cache.get(msgServerID);
    let msgChannel = msgServer.channels.cache.get(msgChannelID);

    // Command (!status): 
    // Check AWS instance status if server is "Dev Server"
    if (msg.content === "!ec2-status") {
        
        const thingy = async () => {

            let instanceStatuses = await getEC2Status();

            let statusText = "Instance Info: \n";
            for (const instanceID in instanceStatuses) {
                statusText += `${instanceID}: ${instanceStatuses[instanceID]}\n`;
            }

            msg.reply(statusText);
        }

        thingy();
    }
});
```

The function that gets triggered in order to get the status of my EC2 instances (the objective of the command) is the following:

```js
// Function: Get the status of all EC2 instances
const getEC2Status = async () => {

    // Variable to store the status of all instances
    let instanceStatuses = {};

    // Retrieve instance information without previous permission check (DryRun = False)
    const results = await ec2.describeInstances({ DryRun: false }, (err, data) => {

        // Return an error if an error ocurrs
        if (err) {
            console.log("Retrieve Instance Info: Error\n", err.stack);
        }
        else {

            // Adds the info of each instance
            data.Reservations.forEach(reservation => {
                let instanceID = reservation.Instances[0].InstanceId;
                let status = reservation.Instances[0].State.Name;
                instanceStatuses[instanceID] = status;
            });

            console.log("Retrieve Instance Info: Success\n", instanceStatuses);
        }

    }).promise();

    return instanceStatuses
}
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around async/await, so that may be the problem. But I need someone to nudge me in the right direction. Right now, I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: You might have multiple instances of your bot running. Check your terminal to see if there are multiple

Comment: Thank you! But I have indeed checked if my bot is running

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the following changes help:

- Make the entire `client.on` function async, instead of only the single `thingy()` function you define in there.
- I'm not sure what the `.promise()` is doing, but I don't think it makes sense to await something after which you call `.promise()`. Remove the `.promise()`.

All in all, thus:

```js
// Event: Message
client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {

    // Extract metadata from message
    let msgServerID = msg.guildId;
    let msgChannelID = msg.channelId;
    let msgUserID = msg.author.id;
    let msgUsername = msg.author.username;

    // Select server and channel of current message
    let msgServer = client.guilds.cache.get(msgServerID);
    let msgChannel = msgServer.channels.cache.get(msgChannelID);

    // Command (!status): 
    // Check AWS instance status if server is "Dev Server"
    if (msg.content === "!ec2-status") {
        
        let instanceStatuses = await getEC2Status();

        let statusText = "Instance Info: \n";
        for (const instanceID in instanceStatuses) {
            statusText += `${instanceID}: ${instanceStatuses[instanceID]}\n`;
        }

        msg.reply(statusText);
    }
});
```

```js
// Function: Get the status of all EC2 instances
const getEC2Status = async () => {

    // Variable to store the status of all instances
    let instanceStatuses = {};

    // Retrieve instance information without previous permission check (DryRun = False)
    const results = await ec2.describeInstances({ DryRun: false }, (err, data) => {

        // Return an error if an error ocurrs
        if (err) {
            console.log("Retrieve Instance Info: Error\n", err.stack);
        }
        else {

            // Adds the info of each instance
            data.Reservations.forEach(reservation => {
                let instanceID = reservation.Instances[0].InstanceId;
                let status = reservation.Instances[0].State.Name;
                instanceStatuses[instanceID] = status;
            });

            console.log("Retrieve Instance Info: Success\n", instanceStatuses);
        }

    });

    return instanceStatuses
}
```

Without more information, I think these are the best first steps.

Comment: Thanks! After implementing some of your changes I have come to a couple conclusions: the ".promise()" is necesary. It converts the regular function call of the AWS-SDK into an await-able function. Made the entire "client.on" callback async, and everything continues to work, but still two calls. After some debugging, seems like the callback to "describeInstances()" is the one that is executing twice, sometimes returning an error on the second time.

Comment: Ah I see, I assumed it was already an async function. I looked up the ec2 documentation and it is indeed correct. I missed that you passed a callback function as the second parameter. Are you saying that you are certain that `getEC2Status` is _not_ being called twice, but only the call to `await ec2.describeInstances(...` is called twice?

Comment: The callback function seems to be executing twice. I put `console.log()` statements around the "describeInstances()" command and nothing prints twice, just the content of the callback.